# Can any one help me to understand this PIC micro controller program?

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, pic

I am an engineering student and I am a little bit confused about this program. Can any one please help me to fill the remaining comments for each lines in the program? I am a newbie to this programming.

```
#INCLUDE<P16F88.INC> ; PIC definitions

SET_UPPER   EQU 0x20
SET_LOWER   EQU 0x21
READ_UPPER  EQU 0x22
READ_LOWER  EQU 0x23
P_gain      EQU 0x24
I_gain      EQU 0x25
D_gain      EQU 0x26
Prop        EQU 0x27
Int         EQU 0x28
Diff        EQU 0x29
DError      EQU 0x30
IError      EQU 0x31
temp        EQU 0x32

    ORG 0h
;****************************
;       INITIZLIZATION
;****************************

    BANKSEL TRISA           ;SELECT TRISA BANL
    MOVLW   B'00000011'     ;MAKE PIN0  AND 1 INPUT
    MOVWF   TRISA           ;Writing to TRISA register
    BANKSEL ANSEL
    MOVLW   B'00000011'     ;MAKE PA0 AND PA1 ANALOG INPUT
    MOVWF   ANSEL
    BANKSEL PORTA
    MOVLW   0x80            ;FOSC/32 AND CHANNEL0
    MOVWF   ADCON0
    MOVLW   0x00
    CLRF    ADCON1          ;LEFT JUSTIFIED ADC VALUE
    CLRF    CCP1CON         ;PWM MODULE
    CLRF    TRISB           ;MAKE PORT B O/P FOR PWM
    MOVLW   0xFF
    MOVWF   PR2
    CLRF    CCPR1L          ;0 DUTY CYCLE AT START
    MOVLW   0x01
    MOVWF   T2CON           ;PRESCALER 4 AND POSTSCALAR 1
    BSF     T2CON,TMR2ON    ;SWITCH ON TIMER
;****************************
;           MAIN
;****************************
MAIN
    CALL    SET_POINT       ;READ SET POINT
    CALL    READ_TEMP       ;READ TEMPERTAURE
    CALL    COMPARE         ;COMPARE AND FIND GAIN VALUE
    CALL    CONTROL         ;MAP GAIN TO DUTY CYCLE
    GOTO    MAIN

;****************************
;       READ SET PT.
;****************************
SET_POINT
    MOVLW   0x80
    MOVWF   ADCON0          ;CHANNEL 0 ADC
    BSF     ADCON0,ADON     ;SWITCH ON ADC
    NOP                     ;WAIT ACQUISITION TIME
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    BSF     ADCON0,GO
ADC 
    BTFSC   ADCON0,GO       ;WAIT TILL CONVERSION IS COMPLETE
    GOTO    ADC
    MOVF    ADRESH,W        ;READ ADC VALUES
    MOVWF   SET_UPPER
    BANKSEL ADRESL
    MOVF    ADRESL,W
    MOVWF   SET_LOWER
    BANKSEL PORTA
    RETURN
;****************************
;      READ TEMPERATURE
;****************************
READ_TEMP
    MOVLW   0x88            ;ADC CHANNEL 1 SELECT
    MOVWF   ADCON0
    BSF     ADCON0,ADON     ;SWITCH ON ADC
    NOP                     ;WAIT ACQUSITION TIME
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    BSF     ADCON0,GO       ;START CONVERSION
ADC0    
    BTFSC   ADCON0,GO       ;WAIT TILL CONVERSION IS COMPLETE
    GOTO    ADC0
    MOVF    ADRESH,W
    MOVWF   READ_UPPER      ;READ ADC VALUE
    BANKSEL ADRESL
    MOVF    ADRESL,W
    MOVWF   READ_LOWER
    BANKSEL PORTA
    RETURN
;******************************
;   COMPUTE ERROR AND GAINS
;******************************
COMPARE
    MOVF    SET_UPPER,W
    SUBWF   READ_UPPER,W    ;SUBTRACT READ VALUE FROM SET POINT
    SUBWF   DError,F        ;COMPUTE INTEGRAL ERROR
    ADDWF   IError,F        ;COMPUTE DIFFERENTIAL ERROR

    MOVWF   Prop            ;MOVE COMPUTED ERROR TO PROP
    MOVF    P_gain,W        
    MOVWF   temp
    MOVF    Prop,W          
Prop_loop
    ADDWF   Prop,F          ;ADD PRPORTIONAL ERROR PROPORTIONAL GAIN TIMES
    DECFSZ  temp,F
    GOTO    Prop_loop

    MOVF    IError,W
    MOVWF   Int
    MOVF    I_gain,W
    MOVWF   temp
    MOVF    Int,W   
Int_loop
    ADDWF   Int,F           ;ADD INTEGRAL ERROR INTEGRAL GAIN TIMES
    DECFSZ  temp,F
    GOTO    Int_loop

    MOVF    DError,W
    MOVWF   Diff
    MOVF    D_gain,W
    MOVWF   temp
    MOVF    Diff,W  
Diff_loop
    ADDWF   Diff,F          ;ADD DIFFERENTIAL ERROR DIFFERENTIAL GAIN TIMES
    DECFSZ  temp,F
    GOTO    Diff_loop
    RETURN
;***************************
;   MAP GAIN TO PWM VALUE
;***************************
CONTROL
    MOVF    Prop,W          ;ADD ALL THREE COMPUTED VALUES
    ADDWF   Int,W
    ADDWF   Diff,W
    MOVWF   CCPR1L          ;MOVE TO CCPR1L TO MAKE IT HI TIME OF PWM
    RETURN

    END
```

Comment: time to get the assembly language manual ? looks like a PID controller for temperature control...based on the comments. I would normally suggest http://electronics.stackexchange.com for PIC questions, but the thorny types over there would close this open question in a second.

Comment: As a matter of good style you generally *wouldn't* have a comment on every line. What don't you get? What the op-codes mean/do? What the program is supposed to accomplish? How the various section are performing the steps?

Comment: definitely an SO question not electronics.so.  Too broad though, ask more specific questions one or a cluster of instructions, not a blanket "finish my homework for me please".  You can edit your question rather than having this one get closed.

Comment: even better, create a real user name, ask the new question with that username, and at least pretend like you plan on coming back and being a part of this community.

Answer (score 0):

I would not add any more comments to such a program.  It seems pretty clear to me unless you have specific questions to ask.  As someone said in the comments, it appears to be a PID control loop that drives a PWM output based on the input of an ADC.

The only unusual thing seems to be integer gains with multiplication by looping (the various `DECFSZ temp,F; GOTO foo_loop` loops).